# Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Function?

Tags: function, flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am defining function in my ChangeNotifier as follows :

```
pickDNIFrontPhoto (ImageSource source,{BuildContext? context}) async {
    try {
      final pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(
        source: source,
      );
      dniPhotoFront = pickedFile;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      _pickImageError = e;
      print("Error picking image $_pickImageError");
    }
  }
```

And passing this function to another widget as follows :

```
PicBox(
     description:'Add DNI Front Photo', 
     path: signupViewModel.dniPhotoFront != null ? signupViewModel.dniPhotoFront!.path : '',
onClick: signupViewModel.pickDNIFrontPhoto(ImageSource.gallery,context: context),
),
```

And in my custom widget i have declared and used the function as follows:

```
final Function? onClick;

 onTap: () async {
              await onClick!();
            },
```

But it gives me this error :

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown building SignUp(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery, _InheritedProviderScope<SignupViewModel>], state: _SignUpState#a0d75):
type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Function?'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SignUp file:///C:/goochil_driver_app/lib/views/login_signup.dart:80:94
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _SignUpState.build (package:goochil_driver_app/views/sign_up.dart:255:80)
#1      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4691:27)
#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4574:15)
#3      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:11)
#4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4267:5)
...
```

What i am doing wrong ? Is the function declaration or onTap assignment. Please a detailed answer to clear my concept as well.

Answer (score 0):

pickDNIFrontPhoto returns a Future when you call it. Instead you want to pass a function not a future. The use of the PicBox widget should be as followed:

```
PicBox(
     description:'Add DNI Front Photo', 
     path: signupViewModel.dniPhotoFront != null ? signupViewModel.dniPhotoFront!.path : '',
onClick: () => signupViewModel.pickDNIFrontPhoto(ImageSource.gallery,context: context),
),
```

Thanks to @Ali Yar Khan for letting me know you also have to change you'r onTap function to look like that:

```
onTap: () {         onClick!();       },
```

Watch the function being passed now. Without the function it'll just call the function pickDNIFrontPhoto and pass the Future it returns instead of a Function.

Comment: error is gone but now the onClick isn't working ...

Comment: i have to change the onTap as well and make it like ```onTap: () {
        onClick!();
      },``` ... add this in your answer i will accept that. Thanks, @YairChen